# How to group and concatenate several rows into groups of 20s

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, concatenation, break

I have a table with only numeric IDs

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And I want to break and concatenate (group) this ids into groups of 5s or 20s, ej.

```
GROUPS
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
```

How can I do this with SQL?

**UPDATE:**

SELECT with sorted ids

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) AS GROUPS
  FROM `test`
  GROUP BY (id - 1) DIV 5
```

Result:

```
  GROUPS
  1,2,3,4,5
  6,7,8,9,10
  11,12,13,14,15
  16,17,18,19,20
  21,22,23,24,25
  26,27,28,29,30
  31,32,33,34,35
```

SELECT with second unsorted table

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) AS GROUPS
  FROM `test2`
  GROUP BY (id - 1) DIV 5
```

Result:

```
  GROUPS
  3,5
  10
  12
  16
  23,24,25
  32,35
  43,44
  47
  55
  61
  68,70
  77
  84
  89
  91,92,95
  97,100
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Did you want those values in a single column with `n` IDs within, separated by commas?

Comment: Are the IDs guaranteed to be without gaps and starting from 1?

Comment: The first answear worked like a charm BUT only if ids are sorted and no id is missing, wich it's not my case:

Comment: Nop, the ids are not guaranteed to be without gaps, I guess there has to be a way to group by a count() of items or creating an extra column on the select that has a correlative number.

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) AS GROUPS
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY (id - 1) DIV 5
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6541/6)

Comment: Your code works great if the IDs are in sequential order, if not it doesn't work, I tried with this solution by adding a secuential row counter but it works weird:

SET @rank=0;<br/>
SELECT<br/>
 id,<br/>
 @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,<br/>
 GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) AS GROUPS<br/>
FROM  `test2`<br/>
group by cast(`rank`/5 as signed)<br/>

Answer (score 2):

For unsorted IDs:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT
    id,
    @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,
    GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) AS GROUPS
FROM  `test2`
GROUP BY (@rank ) DIV 5
```

And the result:

```
+----+------+----------------+
| id | rank | GROUPS         |
+----+------+----------------+
|  1 |    1 | 1,3,5,7,9      |
| 13 |    7 | 11,13,15,17,19 |
| 29 |   15 | 21,23,25,27,29 |
| 31 |   16 | 31,33,35,37,39 |
| 45 |   23 | 41,43,45,47,49 |
| 51 |   26 | 51,53,55,57,59 |
| 61 |   31 | 61,63,65,67,69 |
| 77 |   39 | 71,73,75,77,79 |
| 81 |   41 | 81,83,85,87,89 |
| 93 |   47 | 91,93,95,97,99 |
+----+------+----------------+
```

Thanks a lot for your help, I could't know without your help!

Comment: +1 for a clever but slightly evil solution. I think it's probably about the best way to do it in MySQL since ROW_NUMBER isn't yet supported.

Comment: I really don't know if there is any other way, you give me a great solution with your answer and then I remember that I can add a correlative numbered column, I have heard that Microsoft SQL it's more powerfull in some areas, I wish I had finished high school and have studied computer science, what I know is what I have learn here in the internet, English for instance,  (my native language it's spanish), what I know it's to think and find solutions, a bunch of good tricks and where to find the right answers, again, many many thank you for your help!

Comment: You are right that SQL Server in general has more features. For example it does have the `ROW_NUMBER` function that you could use here. However it doesn't have `GROUP_CONCAT` or anything equivalent (there's a horrible hack using `FOR XML`). So neither database is ideal for solving this problem - you need to hack to work around the missing features in each.